# How to update an embedded document in Laravel with MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I have the following data structure stored with mongodb using Laravel:

```
 "_id": "60e6afe054ee8426460be245",
"firstName": "testUpdateLOL",
"lastName": "TestLast",
"otherName": "TestOther",
"title": "TestTitle",
"company": "TestCompany",
"department": "TestDepartment",
"division": "TestDivision",
"alias": "TestAlias",
"email": "test@test.com",
"enabled": true,
"updatedAt": "1625731078",
"createdAt": "1625731040",
"phone": [
  {
    "description": "home",
    "countryCode": "+44",
    "number": 7773122123,
    "updatedAt": "1625731040",
    "createdAt": "1625731040",
    "_id": "60e6afe054ee8426460be246"
  },
  {
    "description": "work",
    "countryCode": "+58",
    "number": 7773123123,
    "updatedAt": "1625731040",
    "createdAt": "1625731040",
    "_id": "60e6afe054ee8426460be247"
  }
]
```

To update a phone number, I have tried this however it does not work:

```
    $user->update(['phone.0.number' => '101929391']);
```

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks